# Spotlight: Search flagged Mail Messages

Tags: macos, mail.app, spotlight

I'm looking for a way to have all mail messages flagged/labeled with "Red" show up in a saved search in the Finder, but Mail.app flags doesn't seem to be indexed by Spotlight.

Any ideas?

<sup>Mavericks (10.9)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for tags in Spotlight using the following syntax:

```
tag:name
```

For example, to search for all messages with Stack Exchange that are tagged Red, do:

```
Stack Exchange tag:Red
```